# How update all rows in that case : MYSQL + C# dynamic code that calculate different value for each row

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, sql-update

(use mysql + C# .net connector)

The Case:

**table1 input:**

```
item_id| long_name               |short_name
---------------------------------------------
56763  |MY NEW YORK 34 the great |
76878  |in the paris was really..|
```

**table1 ouput:**

```
item_id| long_name               |short_name
---------------------------------------------
56763  |MY NEW YORK 34 the great |NEW YORK
76878  |in the paris was really..|paris
```

I calculate the short_name by C# code

How can it done with UPDATE instead TRUNCATE+INSERT INTO (real table have more then 100,000 rows that have dynamic values separate for each row)?

Comment: and exactly how do you think mysql would be able to figure out that "paris" or "new york" are the critical parts to extract? updating one field's value to be based on another field's value in the same record is **EASY**. figure out how you'll get that newyork/paris bit calculated first.

Comment: What problems have you run into while trying to use UPDATE? If you have the item_id, and you know what the short_name is, it should be a simple query.

Comment: it calculated by c# and not mysql - I asking if my task can be done by update or it have to be done by insert into because i have to calculate short_name values with c#

Comment: you can do it by update: `Update Table1 Set short_name = 'CITY' where item_id = 10` If this is a one time process, or even a very infrequent one you probably don't have to worry about making it super efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data in a `DataTable`, update the columns with your C# function and then update the database like:

```
SqlDataAdapter.Update(Dataset.Tables["table1"]);
```

This will send an `UPDATE` statement for every row though. You should think a bit about your architecture. What do you want to achieve? Is it possible to put the logic in a trigger instead of C# code? Can you reduce the number of rows you have to update by putting another condition (recently added, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, but you are accessing the database from C#, no? I assumed you are using ADO.NET (System.Data) for this. How do you do the truncate+insert at the moment? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have some algorithm which returns the "short name" from the "long name".
Therefore, you need to implement it in SQL, and execute it on the MySQL server.

If you wrote your algorithm in C# - you can make the client program (the C# code) do the calculations, and then, using an `UPDATE` query - update the changes to the database. But for large databases, this is very inefficient and slow (downloading 100,000 rows it quite a bit) -  so you should think of writing in SQL instead.